# regex for extracting a string from a comma-separated alpha-numeric text

Tags: regex

I have a string like the following:

```
http://www.example.com?abc=0,5,ABCD,10&pq=5.1&rs=w.t.f
```

I want to write a regex to extract the `ABCD` part from this.

So far I have been able to get this regex: `.*(abc=[^&]*).*`

It gives me: `abc=0,5,ABCD,10`

But I need only `ABCD` as the output of the regex.

Need help on this.

Comment: In which language/tool are you doing this?

Comment: @anubhava I am doing this in C using apache apr module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use;

```
(?:[^=])(.+?\,){3}
```

http://regex101.com/r/qO4aX0/4

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `abc=0,5,ABCD,10` is **always** 4 comma separated fields you can use this: `abc=.*,.*,(.*),`

see explanation and demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/tV3zC9/1)

the capture group will get the third field.

But I'm pretty sure there's better way to accomplish this in the language you use...

Answer (score 0):

how about.

```
(?<=\d,)[^,]+(?=,\d)
```

see the demo: http://regex101.com/r/iD5yV4/1

Comment: This regex is too restrictive. OP never said 1st, 2nd and 4th parts of `abc=` will be digits.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regex and get the string you want from group index 1.

```
abc=.*?,([^,]*),[^,&]*&
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tV3zC9/2)

**OR**

```
abc=.*?,\K[^,]*(?=,[^,&]*&)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tV3zC9/3)